# wet-vac advice for removing flaking paint from a mortar wall in the basement

Tags: powertools, filter, paint-removal, dust

Not asking for "brand" suggestions but advice on selecting the type/size of tool. This isn't a "shopping" question even though I am shopping.

30 years ago asbestos pipe insulation was removed from 2" black iron heating pipe that runs around the perimeter of the basement just below the floor joists. As part of that remediation the cement-covered stone walls of the basement were sprayed with some kind of paint, to encapsulate any asbestos particles. and that paint is now flaking and peeling terribly. Much of the wall is  bare, friable mortar.  I want to remove the remainder of the paint and repaint the wall with an elastomer-based paint.

I've always heard that wetting things down is the best approach to prevent dust and particles from friable materials from getting into the air, so I was going to spray the wall liberally with water and then try to vacuum the loose stuff off with a wet-vac.  Is there any type/size/style of wet-vac (gallons, horsepower, CFM, hose-diameter, filtration capability, vacuum-wand-type, etc)  that is better suited to handling dampened mortar-dust and wetted flakes of peeling paint?

When I was looking on the manufacturers' websites the advice there is to use their HEPA filters only for dry-vacuuming. How can I keep the dust from escaping the vacuum canister?

Comment: Bigger vacuums hold more. Stronger vacuums suck more. Bigger, stronger vacuums get the job done faster. They also take more space in your garage. Decide on a price point and buy one. All messes are more or less the same, and you aren't really buying the tool for this one job.

Comment: Is there no difference in filtration capabilities when the HEPA filter is eliminated and the wet-vac is being used? They're all pretty much the same in terms of wet-vac dust control?

Comment: There is no filtration other than what you have installed, and there are filters designed for wet use They're wide open otherwise, such as when I'm pumping the sludge out of my water feature in the spring.

Comment: Wet vac? I would think that this task requires scrubbing or a high-pressure cleaner.

Comment: @Jasen: the paint is barely attached to the powdery cement. It falls off at the slightest touch.  I'm most concerned about dust management.

Comment: use a wet broom